# How to make the background color transparent

Tags: css

I'm using a webgrid to display the data and it displays the data in alternate and i have hard-coded the background color in one of the row and it works fine with one but not with the other, i'm not sure if this is the right approach to do.

my question is: how can I make it transparent to the background?

here is the pic:

[image]

here is the source code:

```
<tr class="webgrid-row-style">            
            <td><input readonly name="rowNumber_0" value="1" style="width:40px;border:0; background-color:#F5F5F5;" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Location" name="location_0" value="DATA CENTER" style="width:250px;" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="RackShelf" name="rack_0" value="23" style="width:50px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="DCLocation" name="dcLocation_0" value="71-"   /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Customer" name="customer_0" value="worth" style="width:250px;" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="SerialNumber" name="serialNumber_0" value="5" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Location" name="location_0" value="DATA CENTER" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td><input readonly name="rowNumber_1" value="2" style="width:40px;border:0; background-color:#F5F5F5;" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Location" name="location_1" value="DATA CENTER" style="width:250px;" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="RackShelf" name="rack_1" value="9" style="width:50px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="DCLocation" name="dcLocation_1" value="BD37:"   /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Customer" name="customer_1" value="Family Services" style="width:250px;" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="SerialNumber" name="serialNumber_1" value="USE" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Location" name="location_1" value="DATA CENTER" /></td>
        </tr>
```

//css

```
 .webgrid-row-style {
        padding: 3px 7px 2px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .webgrid-alternating-row {
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
        padding: 3px 7px 2px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

for both ,

```
.webgrid-row-style, .webgrid-alternating-row {
    background-color: transparent
}
```

and since you're using an `input` in each `td`, add this style too

```
.webgrid-row-style td input, .webgrid-alternating-row td input{
    background-color: transparent
}
```

[**background-color**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color)

Comment: @AbuHamzah: for both row-style and alternating-row

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the input to have the same background color as its parent (`td`) you could use `background-color:inherit`

```css
.webgrid-row-style {
        padding: 3px 7px 2px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .webgrid-alternating-row {
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
        padding: 3px 7px 2px;
    }
```

```html
<table border="0">
<tr class="webgrid-row-style">            
            <td><input readonly name="rowNumber_0" value="1" style="width:40px;border:0; background-color:inherit" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Location" name="location_0" value="DATA CENTER" style="width:250px;" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="RackShelf" name="rack_0" value="23" style="width:50px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="DCLocation" name="dcLocation_0" value="71-"   /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Customer" name="customer_0" value="worth" style="width:250px;" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="SerialNumber" name="serialNumber_0" value="5" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Location" name="location_0" value="DATA CENTER" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td><input readonly name="rowNumber_1" value="2" style="width:40px;border:0; background-color:inherit;" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Location" name="location_1" value="DATA CENTER" style="width:250px;" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="RackShelf" name="rack_1" value="9" style="width:50px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="DCLocation" name="dcLocation_1" value="BD37:"   /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Customer" name="customer_1" value="Family Services" style="width:250px;" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="SerialNumber" name="serialNumber_1" value="USE" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Location" name="location_1" value="DATA CENTER" /></td>
        </tr>
  </table>
```

On a side note, avoid inline styles where possible.

Answer (score 1):

This CSS should do it:

```
tr.webgrid-row-style td input {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Note: if you're using Google Chrome (you probably should be) right click the element and click inspect element. Once Chrome's developer tools are open, right click the element and you can copy it's CSS path directly from there (when you aren't sure exactly how to target a DOM element with CSS).

Answer (score 1):

You could always use background-color: rgba(c value,c value,c value,alpha value)

```
background-color: rgba(245,245,245,0.5);
```

As seen above using rgba allows you to specify an alpha colour.

Answer (score 1):

remove css from your element

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k4xny29h/)

```
<tr class="webgrid-row-style">
    <td>
        <input readonly name="rowNumber_0" value="1" style="width:40px;border:0;" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="Location" name="location_0" value="DATA CENTER" style="width:250px;" />
        </t <td>
        <input type="text" id="RackShelf" name="rack_0" value="23" style="width:50px;" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="DCLocation" name="dcLocation_0" value="71-" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="Customer" name="customer_0" value="worth" style="width:250px;" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="SerialNumber" name="serialNumber_0" value="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="Location" name="location_0" value="DATA CENTER" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
    <td>
        <input readonly name="rowNumber_1" value="2" style="width:40px;border:0;" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="Location" name="location_1" value="DATA CENTER" style="width:250px;" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="RackShelf" name="rack_1" value="9" style="width:50px;" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="DCLocation" name="dcLocation_1" value="BD37:" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="Customer" name="customer_1" value="Family Services" style="width:250px;" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="SerialNumber" name="serialNumber_1" value="USE" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="Location" name="location_1" value="DATA CENTER" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

css

```
.webgrid-row-style input:not([type]) {
    padding: 3px 7px 2px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.webgrid-alternating-row input:not([type]) {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    padding: 3px 7px 2px;
}
```